# Storing image in a server directly from android mobile

Tags: php, android, mysql, storage

I want to capture image from android device and storing them in server.

This server should to be ready for reading from PHP file for image retrieval.

who can to recommend for this specific server?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by Multipart Entity or Via Ftp server.